# Name resolution works with host but fails otherwise

Tags: networking, dns, windows-subsystem-for-linux, resolv.conf

Ubuntu bash on Windows 10

I have an issue where the host and nslookup commands resolve all hosts just fine but all other commands fail domain resolution. See below:

```
user@computer:/mnt/c/Users/user$ host google.com
 google.com has address 172.217.12.174
 google.com has IPv6 address 2607:f8b0:4006:81a::200e
 google.com mail is handled by 50 alt4.aspmx.l.google.com.
 google.com mail is handled by 30 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.
 google.com mail is handled by 40 alt3.aspmx.l.google.com.
 google.com mail is handled by 10 aspmx.l.google.com.
 google.com mail is handled by 20 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.
user@computer:/mnt/c/Users/user$ ping google.com
 ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
user@computer:/mnt/c/Users/user$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
 nameserver 8.8.8.8
 search domain.com
user@computer:/mnt/c/Users/user$ lsb_release -a
 No LSB modules are available.
 Distributor ID: Ubuntu
 Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
 Release:        18.04
 Codename:       bionic
user@computer:/mnt/c/Users/user$ ping 8.8.8.8
 PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
 64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=122 time=18.6 ms
 64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=122 time=17.7 ms
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue where Windows has applied updates to the sub system but a reboot has not occurred. A full reboot (of windows, not Linux Subsystem) solves this.